# How to decompress the request received in compressed format using zlib's inflate algorithm over webSocket connection in python

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, compression

I am establishing the WebSocket connection to an end point and enter into listening mode, So the request that I am receiving is in compressed format using Zlib's inflate algorithm.I need to decompress it in python.Currently, it's throwing me below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Agent.py", line 305, in <module>
result = ws.recv()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 
293, in recv
opcode, data = self.recv_data()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 
310, in recv_data
opcode, frame = self.recv_data_frame(control_frame)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 
334, in recv_data_frame
return self.cont_frame.extract(frame)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 
424, in extract
"cannot decode: " + repr(frame.data))
 websocket._exceptions.WebSocketPayloadException: cannot decode:   
 '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x9dUm 
  k\xeb6\x14\xfe+\xc1\x1f\x
```

Any suggestion as in how can I decode this in python over that web socket connection?